# Sharing authentication token between two cordova apps

Tags: cordova, authentication, token, adfs

At our project we are developing two cordova apps that authenticate against the same ADFS provider.

Our intention is to propagate the login info of one of those two to the other one, retrieving the token from the first application and sending it via intent to the other one. Is it possible?

If so, how do we retrieve the token from the first webview and set it in the second webview?

I've been checking by modifying the source code of a plugin, and for sure the token is being stored in a session cookie. However, I can't find any way to retrieve it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Would you please update your question to include the code you have used so we can best answer it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [ADAL library](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/connecting-adfs-to-a-cordova-application-64cb9a389e52) for both applications, then you will get SSO across them.

They will each have their own token but when you log into the second one after login into the first, you won't see a login screen.

Not sure why you want to "share" the token but since they both connect to the same ADFS RP, the claims in the token for each application will be identical.